# when calculating time, it doesn't account for a different day

Tags: c#

I have this code that calculates time. but when it goes in to the next day it sort of resets and doesn't keep going forward. what im trying to do is when it goes past 12AM, to keep counting the hours and print the result as 10, and not go back to 3

```
            string entry_T = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();

            int delta_day = Int32.Parse(entry_T.Substring(8, 2)) - Int32.Parse(DT.Substring(8, 2));
            int st_h = Int32.Parse(entry_T.Substring(11, 2));
            int ed_h = Int32.Parse(DT.Substring(11, 2));
            int st_m = Int32.Parse(entry_T.Substring(14, 2));
            int ed_m = Int32.Parse(DT.Substring(14, 2));
            double delta_T = ((ed_h + 24 * delta_day) * 60 + ed_m - st_h * 60 - st_m) / 60.0;
            if (delta_T <= 1) print = 3;
            else if (delta_T <= 2) print = 5;
            else if (delta_T <= 3) print = 7;
            else if (delta_T <= 4) print = 8;
            else print = 10;
            return cost;
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of the behavior you want?  Your description is unclear.

Comment: The solution to your problem is to stop using that howbrew and start using DateTime. You are trying to reinvent the wheel, when you have a fully gassed car - with keys in the ignition - just standing there.

Answer (score 3):

You can subtract 2 DateTimes to get a TimeSpan.

```
var dt1 = DateTime.Parse(your_string);
var timeSpan = DateTime.Now - dt1;

//timeSpan will tell you the difference, corrected for anomalies like leap years.
```

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netcore-3.1